# Can someone help me identify this Ficus plant?

Tags: botany

I have a bonsai with me which I grew from a seedling germinated in my backyard. It's been with me for the last 5-6 years. I definitely know its a Ficus, but I am not able to identify which species it belongs to. I have provided pictures of the specimen below:
[image]

[image]

I need to know if its F.virens (white fig) or F.ingens (Red leaf ficus). This specimen is from Kerala, INDIA.

Comment: There are up to 900 different species within the Ficus genus... you might want to add in some more detail e.g. location, measurements, the shape of different sections of the plants (which can be done by taking more photos of different parts through different perspectives). Also, keep in mind that, without genetic testing, it may be difficult for *most* people to identify which exact species this is with the absolute certainty.

Comment: This is a Ficus Bonsai, size and shape wont be natural. However its from Kerala India